# Project Loom: carrier pinning

Tags: java, project-loom

Why native code leads to carrier pinning? Is it because to switch carrier thread to another virtual thread, it should be parked from Java code?

Also, why File I/O pins a carrier thread as well right now? Is it because there is no async File IO support at Linux? (googled aio, but it looks like it is not very clear)

Are there any other examples, when carrier pinning occurs?

Comment: I suggest you provide links to the sources that informed you of these issues.

Answer (score 0):

About carrier pinning as of May 2020: [https://cr.openjdk.java.net/~rpressler/loom/loom/sol1_part1.html#pinning](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Erpressler/loom/loom/sol1_part1.html#pinning)

Comment: An answer should be self contained with links as reference